# Pytorch expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, bert-language-model

When running this code: `embedding_matrix = torch.stack(embeddings)`

I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [7, 768] at entry 0 and [8, 768] at entry 1
```

I'm trying to get embedding using BERT via:

```
    split_sent = sent.split()
    tokens_embedding = []
    j = 0
    for full_token in split_sent:
        curr_token = ''
        x = 0
        for i,_ in enumerate(tokenized_sent[1:]): 
            token = tokenized_sent[i+j]
            piece_embedding = bert_embedding[i+j]
            if token == full_token and curr_token == '' :
               tokens_embedding.append(piece_embedding)
               j += 1
               break                                     
    sent_embedding = torch.stack(tokens_embedding)
    embeddings.append(sent_embedding)
embedding_matrix = torch.stack(embeddings)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [PyTorch Docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.stack.html) about `torch.stack()` function, it needs the input tensors in the same shape to stack. I don't know how will you be using the `embedding_matrix` but either you can add padding to your tensors (which will be a list of zeros at the end till a certain user-defined length and is recommended if you will train with this stacked tensor, refer [this tutorial](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/09/an-explanatory-guide-to-bert-tokenizer/)) to make them equidimensional or you can simply use something like `torch.cat(data,dim=0)`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I will convert `embedding_matrix` to an `array` to be passed in the weight layer as an updated layer in the Keras model. I tried to use `cat` before but got a problem with GPU memory (OOM).  i have 150000 sentences and got 13 million and 973000 words in the array that caused OOM . so what is the best i should do ?

Comment: Generic attention models have an input limit of 512 or 1024 (large models). So my idea would be to break the larger sentences into chunks of 256 or 512 (according to your GPU VRAM). And if you like the answer do give a thumb-up. It keeps my motivation up to help as many guys as I can!

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer but don't have enough reputations. Excuse me, in general should i need the total words that have embedded in the layer that will be update or i should need the total sentences . i mean if i have 150000 sentences should that layer that will be update like

    `se1 = Embedding(150000, 768, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)`
or i should need the total words like

    `se1 = Embedding(1393860, 768, mask_zero=True)(inputs2)`

Comment: What I meant with my last comment was to make one tensor for each sentence, So you will have 150000 tensors. You can get both word embedding and sentence embeddings from BERT. But I would recommend going for sentence one, to save the problem of stacking. And you can follow through the lines mentioned in the link: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/62658/how-to-get-sentence-embedding-using-bert

Comment: you mean i should pass sentence by sentence to tensor and for the model ? not all of them in once ?

Comment: yes, sentence by sentence.. not all of them at once. The current attention models cannot make sense of large paragraphs.. which is why there has not been much progress in content generation language models.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping and replying .. so excuse me how can I control in passing sentence by sentence? I read the link but didn't get exactly what I need to change?

Comment: The data science stackexchange link that I have given to you in the last comment, You can see that all the the work has been done over the variable `sentence`. And you have to do on a list of sentences. Which you have beforehand. So you might have to implement everything in a for loop over the list of sentences.

Comment: i will accept the answer as you helped me a lot, i will try it