# DataLoader error: RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1024] at entry 0 and [212] at entry 13

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset composed of a column name `input_ids` that I'm loading with a `DataLoader`:

```
train_batch_size = 2
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=train_batch_size)
```

The length of `eval_dataloader` is

```
print(len(eval_dataloader))
>>> 1623
```

I'm getting the error when I run:

```
for step, batch in enumerate(eval_dataloader):
    print(step)
>>> 1,2... ,1621
```

Each batch length is `1024`. If I change `train_batch_size` to 1 the error disappears.

I tried removing the last batch with

```
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=train_batch_size, drop_last=True)
```

But the error still pops up with batch of size greater than 1.

The complete stack:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 2
      1 eval_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset,shuffle=True,batch_size=2,drop_last=True) 
----> 2 for step, batch in enumerate(eval_dataloader):
      3     print(step, batch['input_ids'].shape)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:628, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    625 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    626     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    627     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 628 data = self._next_data()
    629 self._num_yielded += 1
    630 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    631         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    632         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py:671, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    669 def _next_data(self):
    670     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 671     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    672     if self._pin_memory:
    673         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py:61, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     59 else:
     60     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 61 return self.collate_fn(data)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:265, in default_collate(batch)
    204 def default_collate(batch):
    205     r"""
    206         Function that takes in a batch of data and puts the elements within the batch
    207         into a tensor with an additional outer dimension - batch size. The exact output type can be
   (...)
    263             >>> default_collate(batch)  # Handle `CustomType` automatically
    264     """
--> 265     return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:128, in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    126 if isinstance(elem, collections.abc.Mapping):
    127     try:
--> 128         return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
    129     except TypeError:
    130         # The mapping type may not support `__init__(iterable)`.
    131         return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:128, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    126 if isinstance(elem, collections.abc.Mapping):
    127     try:
--> 128         return elem_type({key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem})
    129     except TypeError:
    130         # The mapping type may not support `__init__(iterable)`.
    131         return {key: collate([d[key] for d in batch], collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for key in elem}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:120, in collate(batch, collate_fn_map)
    118 if collate_fn_map is not None:
    119     if elem_type in collate_fn_map:
--> 120         return collate_fn_map[elem_type](batch, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map)
    122     for collate_type in collate_fn_map:
    123         if isinstance(elem, collate_type):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/cilm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py:163, in collate_tensor_fn(batch, collate_fn_map)
    161     storage = elem.storage()._new_shared(numel, device=elem.device)
    162     out = elem.new(storage).resize_(len(batch), *list(elem.size()))
--> 163 return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)

RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [212] at entry 0 and [1024] at entry 1
```

I found other somewhat similar SO questions / regular questions, but they seem to be related to the `stack` function in other settings ([link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-but-got-3-224-224-at-entry-0-and-3-224-336-at-entry-3/87211), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011333/pytorch-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size), [link](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/error-stack-expects-each-tensor-to-be-equal-size-but-got-24-at-entry-0-and-81-at-entry-1/43338), [link](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch/issues/472))

Similar issue exist in the `train_dataloader`:
`RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [930] at entry 0 and [1024] at entry 1`

**Update**
Solved it thanks to @chro and [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/ro63pm/stack_expects_each_tensor_to_be_equal_size_but/): "To isolate the problem loop over the items in the dataloader with batch size 1 without shuffle and print the shape of the array you got. Then investigate the ones with different sizes".

Seems like there was a sequence that wasn't of length `1024`, but this cannot be seen for some reason if the batch is not of size 1. Not entirely sure how you can have a tensor of tensors with varying lengths, but alas. To resolve the issue I filtered my dataset first and removed the 1 sequence that was not `1024`. Then called the `DataLoader` on it.

Comment: Could you check  for correctness  of exact tensor element in validation which is produced 212?
In train it is works with shuffle=True and drop_last=True. 
What is the point of dropping validation elements?
 In many cases validation dataset proceeds with batch_size=1 especially if you freeze batch_norm layers.

Comment: @chro I'm honestly not sure where the 212 is coming from. Each batch shape is 1024. Regarding the dropping of the last element, I was just trying to figure out if that will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Could you debug it with (replace `batch.shape` with relevant code to your data)

```
eval_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset,
                             batch_size=1) 
for step, batch in enumerate(eval_dataloader):
    if batch.shape[1]!=1024:
        print(step, batch.shape)
```

My idea is to check the following:

1. Does it fails on the same item in dataset?
2. What is the shape of item it fails?

Usually I see this error when it stacks several elements in DataLoader, but some of the elements are in different size.

Please, also write a complete stack trace related to problem.

Update:
**To resolve the issue  filter dataset first and removed the 1 sequence that was not same with others. Then called the DataLoader on it**

Comment: Doesn't seem like it fails on the same element actually! When running multiple times, it stops at: `791 torch.Size([2, 1024])` or `919 torch.Size([2, 1024])` or `752 torch.Size([2, 1024])`. But always the same error: `RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [212] at entry 0 and [1024] at entry 1`

Comment: Added the full stack! Also, all of the batches are the same size as I mentioned: 480 torch.Size([2, 1024])
481 torch.Size([2, 1024])
482 torch.Size([2, 1024])
483 torch.Size([2, 1024])
484 torch.Size([2, 1024])
485 torch.Size([2, 1024])
486 torch.Size([2, 1024])
487 torch.Size([2, 1024])
488 torch.Size([2, 1024])
489 torch.Size([2, 1024])
490 torch.Size([2, 1024])
491 torch.Size([2, 1024])
492 torch.Size([2, 1024])
493 torch.Size([2, 1024])

Comment: Solved it! See my update! Thanks a lot for the help. If you'll update your answer with my update I'll accept it as the answer